# Django: Filter a Queryset made of unions not working

Tags: python, django

I defined 3 models related with M2M relationsships

```
class Suite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    suites = models.ManyToManyField(Suite)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
    Actions = models.ManyToManyField(Action)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In one of my views I tried to collect all the **Suite**s related to an specific **User**. The user may be related to several **Role**s that can contain many **Suite**s. And then filter **Suite**s by name. But the filter seem to have no effects

```
queryset = Suite.objects.union(*(role.suites.all() for role in 
self.get_user().role_set.all()))
repr(self.queryset)

'<QuerySet [<Suite: energia>, <Suite: waste 4 thing>]>'

self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(name="energia")
repr(self.queryset)

'<QuerySet [<Suite: energia>, <Suite: waste 4 thing>]>'
```

The query atribute inside the queryset  not alter its content before executin the filter:

```
(SELECT "navbar_suite"."id", "navbar_suite"."name", "navbar_suite"."title", "navbar_suite"."icon" FROM "navbar_suite") UNION (SELECT "navbar_suite"."id", "navbar_suite"."name", "navbar_suite"."title", "navbar_suite"."icon" FROM "navbar_suite" INNER JOIN "navbar_role_suites" ON ("navbar_suite"."id" = "navbar_role_suites"."suite_id") WHERE "navbar_role_suites"."role_id" = 1)

(SELECT "navbar_suite"."id", "navbar_suite"."name", "navbar_suite"."title", "navbar_suite"."icon" FROM "navbar_suite") UNION (SELECT "navbar_suite"."id", "navbar_suite"."name", "navbar_suite"."title", "navbar_suite"."icon" FROM "navbar_suite" INNER JOIN "navbar_role_suites" ON ("navbar_suite"."id" = "navbar_role_suites"."suite_id") WHERE "navbar_role_suites"."role_id" = 1)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As stated in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#union), only `count()`, `order_by()`, `values()`, `values_list()` and slicing of union queryset is allowed. You can't filter on union queryset.

That means, you have to apply filters on queries before applying union on them.

Also, you can achieve your goal without even using `union()`:

```
Suite.objects.filter(role_set__users=self.get_user(), name="energia")
```

You may need to adjust field name in filter if you've used `related_name` or `related_query_name` in definition of `suites` M2M field in `Role` model.

Comment: If it's not allowed, it should really raise an exception instead of silently do nothing like it seems to do.

Comment: Wow! That is terrible that there is no warning or error that filtering is unsupported and will be a no-op. This burned me bad. I'm interested in whether there are any alternatives to `.union` that don't disable filtering.

Comment: You can still filter all queries before joining them using `.union` or use any other alternative for that statement. There is no drop-in replacement for union that will always work the same. And I agree that this is unfortunate design decision...

Comment: I opened an [issue on the bug tracker](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30639).

Comment: One of the worst Django's trap I've met.

Comment: Looks like the same thing happens with .difference

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and ended up using the union query as a subquery so that the filters could work:

```
yourModelUnionSubQuerySet = YourModelQS1.union(YourModelQS2)
yourModelUnionQuerySet = YourModel.objects.filter(id__in=yourModelUnionSubQuerySet.values('id'))
```

Comment: Great answer when you no have other option than use union.

Comment: It's solved by issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Even better than using the slow `in` search lookup is to use the `Exists` subquery. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries

Comment: @NiccolòMineo please could you give an example of using the Exists subquery instead of `in`?

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple solution. Just use

```
self.queryset = self.queryset | <querySet you want to append>
```

instead of

```
self.queryset = self.queryset.union(<QuerySet you want to append>)
```

Worked for me. I hope this is understandable. After this you will be able to use filter.

Comment: CAREFUL! This is NOT identical to using `.union`! This bit me pretty bad, very odd bugs can arise when you do this. It merges the querysets, it does not "union" them.

Comment: Yeah sure will keep it mind. It has got be out of very tricky situation though. 
It allows to use annotate to the result and union does not. I learned about this operator in that problem. Was a live saver then. 
Thanks i will keep you comment in mind.

Comment: FYI `|` is the "OR" operator. It may work for some use cases depending on what someone is trying to do. It is not really "merging" QuerySets as I have seen the behavior described, it adds an extra `OR` to the `WHERE` portion of the output SQL essentially. Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#or