# Django: generate queryset with duplicates

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-queryset

I need to make a queryset with duplicated items for testing purpose in Django, like:

```
<QuerySet [<MyModel: instance1>, <MyModel: instance1>, <MyModel: instance2>]>
```

What is the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Join with a related model that acts as a multiplier.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you give an example?

Comment: For example if you have two `User`s, and three `Post`s, one written by user 1, and two by user 2, then by `JOIN`ing, it will result in user 2 occurring multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

You can use django's [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#union) function with `all=True` parameter, e.g.:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(...).union(MyModel.objects.filter(...), all=True)
```

Then you can use some condition that will result in a non-empty intersection, e.g.:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).union(MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 2]), all=True)
```

Comment: Be warned that union querysets don't act the same way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260393/django-filter-a-queryset-made-of-unions-not-working