# How to filter a Django queryset, after it is modified in a loop

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have recently been working with Django, and it has been confusing me a lot (although I also like it).

The problem I am facing right now is when I am looping, and in the loop modifying the queryset, in the next loop the `.filter` is not working.

So let's take the following simplified example:

I have a dictionary that is made from the queryset like this
`animal_dict` = {chicken: 6,
cows: 7,
fish: 1,
sheep: 2}

The queryset is called `self.animals`

```
for key in dict:
    if dict[key] < 3:
        remove_animal = max(dict, key=dict.get)
        remove = self.animals.filter(animal = remove_animal)[-2:]
        self.animals = self.animals.difference(remove)
        key[replaced_industry] = key[replaced_industry] - 2
```

What I am trying to do is as follows: my goal is that there needs to be a balance under the animals. So since there are not enough **fish**, 2 of the animals with the highest n have to go (**cows**). And then in the second loop - since there are not enough **sheep**, 2 of the animals with the highest n have to go again (**chicken**).

Now the first time it loops (with **fish**), the `.filter` does exactly as it should. However, when I loop it a second time (for **sheep**), the `remove = self.animals.filter(animal = remove_animal)[-2:]` gives me an output is not in line with `animal =` filter. When I print the `remove` in the second loop, it returns a list of all different animals (instead of just 1).

After the loops, the `dict` should look like this: {chicken: 4,
cows: 5,
fish: 1,
sheep: 2}
This because first cow will go down 2 and it is the `max`, and then chicken will go down 2, as it is then the `max`

I am definitely missing some Django logic here, but to me this seems very strange. I hope the question is well-understood, else happy to clarify further.

Comment: Please don't use `dict` as a variable name, it will override the reference to the `dict` class. As for replacing items, exactly *what* are you trying to do? It is usally *not* a good idea to create queries in a loop, since that will result in a *lot* of rountrips to the database.

Comment: Remember one thing: NEVER make an SQL query in a loop. Its a performance killer. Make the query first than use the result and go on....

Comment: So dict is actually not the name of the dictionary, it was just to make it more clear (but I changed it now)

My goal is that there needs to be a balance under the animals. So since there are not enough fish, 2 of the animals with the highest n have to go. And then in the second loop - since there are not enough sheep, 2 of the animals with the highest n have to go again

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, every time you call `self.animals.filter` you are making a request to the database, and this should not be done in a loop.

It isn't very clear what you are trying to achieve, but it seems like you want the number of each type of animal to be (almost?) the same number, and that the only operation you can perform on it is reducing the number of animals.

Its always better to avoid loops if you can.

If you want them all to be the same number, and you can only reduce the number of animals you have, then the best solution would be

```
fewest_number = min(self.animals.values())
self.animals = {animal: fewest_number for animal in self.animals.keys()}
```

If you want, to say, allow a tolerance +1 of the fewest animal

```
fewest_number = min(self.animals.values()) + 1
self.animals = {animal: fewest_number for animal in self.animals.keys()}
```

If you can increase the number of each type of animal, then you could find the average:

```
average_number = sum(self.animals.values()) / len(self.animals)
self.animals = {animal: average_number for animal in self.animals.keys()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. Apparently it didn't work because only `count()`, `order_by()`, `values()`, `values_list()` and slicing of union queryset is allowed. You can't filter on union queryset and the same applies to `.difference`.

More about this here: [Django: Filter a Queryset made of unions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260393/django-filter-a-queryset-made-of-unions-not-working/49261966)

Because in the second loop it is made into a union queryset, the filter function simply doesn't work. The weird thing is that this doesn't show an error, but will simply not filter, what makes it hard to detect.